# Git Pull command really do

Tags: git

Im just confused, what does git pull really do? 
I have a local branch with the latest code repository, and run the command git pull that consist a new file test.txt (remote) but it is not a latest code repository, does it overwrite all the files in my local branch by the remote branch?

Comment: Perhaps reading the [documentaiton](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) will help clear you up?

Comment: [Pull is fetch then merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` is no more than a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. It does not replace the code on your local branch.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [git-pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) documentation:

> More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and
>   calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current
>   branch.

[git-fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

> Fetches named heads or tags from one or more other repositories, along
>   with the objects necessary to complete them.

[git-merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their
>   histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.
>   This command is used by git pull to incorporate changes from another
>   repository and can be used by hand to merge changes from one branch
>   into another.

So to conclude `git-pull` command simply combine `git-fetch` and `git-merge` command.